# How to add image background using String path from database in android studio?

Tags: android, database, string, path, imageview

Ok, after searching and browsing over the internet, I just didn't get what I was looking for. I have a database with a field for "Path", where my images file names are listed.

```
**Table1:**

PATH             ID
imgRice.jpg      1
imgMango.jpg     2 
imgBanana.jpg    3
```

Now I want my imageView to change picture accordingly from my query:

```
"Select Path from table1 where ID = 1";
```

I will declare a String, like `String queryResultString` to handle the result (ex.imgRice.jpg).

I want a code that looks like `imgView.image="drawable/" + queryResultString`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: is this an external mysql database or an sqllite database?

Comment: **1** - you must not add the `extension` to the file name. **2** - you can use `reflection` for this (already answered a 1000 times on StackOverflow and a godzillion times on Google).

Comment: internal database sir helldawg13

Comment: sir frank, what is 'reflection'?

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/learn-java-for-android-development-reflection-basics--mobile-3203

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments and suggestions guys, highly appreciated.
But I've got a simple yet tricky turnaround for my problem.

**First**, it is IMPOSSIBLE to rip the Drawable path because it is compressed when published to .apk file.

**Second**, to make it possible, you need to use id for every file in your drawable.

**Third**, it is much better to add files(images) to asset folder(\app\src\main\assets).

**Lastly**, follow these simple codes:

```
//code to initiate the object ImageView...
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic);//pic is the id of ImageView in my xml file...

                    try 
                    {
                        // now, get the input stream
                        InputStream input= getAssets().open(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("image")));//image is the name of field in my db which holds the path (ex. rice.jpg)...
                        // initiate image as drawable
                        Drawable draw = Drawable.createFromStream(input, null);
                        // set image to ImageView
                        myImage.setImageDrawable(draw);
                    }

                    catch(IOException ex) 
                    {
                        return;
                    }
```

Enjoy Coding! ^_^